# How to insert custom field in Joomla 1.6 article editor?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.6, joomla-article

I want to insert a custom field in the **Article edit** page in the administration area of Joomla 1.6. Please see screenshot.

http://screencast.com/t/vtLEBdUK

I have tried to edit `myjoomlasite/administrator/components/com_content/models/forms/article.xml`.

I can introduce a field in the article options fieldset, but not in the main edit area.

Answer (score 3):

For insert a custom field in the Article edit page in the administration you need to change in two files

1. myjoomlasite/administrator/components/com_content/models/forms/article.xml

   add your field name like below code

   ```
   <field name="name" type="text" label="JGLOBAL_NAME"
       description="JFIELD_NAME_DESC" class="inputbox" size="30"
       required="true" />
   ```
2. myjoomlasite/administrator/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/edit.php

   add your label and input field

   ```
   <?php echo $this->form->getLabel('name'); ?>
   <?php echo $this->form->getInput('name'); ?>
   ```

Comment: You'll also need to add a reference to the new fields in the ``/components/com_content/models/article.php`` file around line 84.

Comment: This Answer has little shortcoming like the new custom field is added in the new article post-page but its not visible in the edit/update post page

Comment: +1 Thanks Mate! I've been scratching my head from past 2 days!

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend modifying the core files to achieve what you want.

You could use one of Joomla's CCK (content construction kits) to create your content templates.

Best free CCKs available for Joomla :

1. [Form2Content](http://www.form2content.com/) (my favorite)
2. [K2](http://getk2.org/) (most popular, highly recommended)

You can find more in [Joomla Extension Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-production/content-construction)

Answer (score 0):

you can add custom fields to the article component (com_content), without the need to change core files in this link: http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_the_article_component